# Merge data inside foreach in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I create function inside Model.
Variable `$category=1,2,3;` is string

I want that function to look in table categories and to return me name of this ids in one variable to be like `$categoryName=first,second,third`

```
public function getCategory($category){
    $names = explode(",",$category);

    foreach ($names as $name){
        $categories = DB::table('categories')->where('id',$name)->first();
        $categoryName = implode(',',(array)$categories->name);
    }
    return $this->$categoryName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, what you want to do can be done as following.

```
public function getCategory($categoryIds) // ex) 1,2,3
{

    $categoryIdArray = explode(",", $categoryIds); // [1,2,3]
    $categoryName = '';
    foreach ($categoryIdArray as $categoryId){
      $category = DB::table('categories')->where('id',$categoryId)->first();
      $categoryName .= $category->name . ',';
    }
    $categoryName = substr($categoryName, 0, -1);
    return $categoryName;
}
```

However, the example above don't make use of the advantage of `Model`.

Does the `Model` which have `getCategory` method have `category_ids` attribute?

If it is, you can write as follows.

```
public function getCategory()
{

    $categoryIdArray = explode(",", $this->category_ids);
    $categoryName = '';
    foreach ($categoryIdArray as $categoryId){
      $category = DB::table('categories')->where('id',$categoryId)->first();
      $categoryName .= $category->name . ',';
    }
    $categoryName = substr($categoryName, 0, -1);
    return $categoryName;
}
```

You can access `category_ids` which have `1,2,3` value for instance via `$this` so it doesn't need `argument`.

To do moreover effectively, you can have `category_id` attribute in another model.

In that case, you can do above more simply.

**Reference:** 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop over your ids and do multiple DB queries - you can get them all with just one query using `whereIn`

```
public function getCategory($category) {
    $ids = explode(",",$category);
    $categories = DB::table('categories')->whereIn('id',$ids)->get();
    return $categories->implode('name', ',');
}
```

More [info about whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses) in the docs.

However it would be neater to do this using Eloquent, the Laravel way, for example (this assumes you have a Category model to match your categories table):

```
public function getCategory($category) {
    $ids = explode(",",$category);
    $categories = App\Category::find($ids);
    return $categories->implode('name', ',');
}
```

More [info about retrieving models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models) in the docs.

Comment: Oops I realised you wanted a string returned; my initial code returned a collection.  I've updated my answer to return a string.